# Did Danzo use Shuisui's eye to become Hokage?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto Shippuden, Danzo has a sharingan with powers that allows him to control the mind of his victims as it is shown in the 5 Kage Submit. In the 197th episode, after Pain's attack, some of the heads of the Land of Fire meet to decide what to do next and who should be the next Hokage. Kakashi should have been chosen but Danzo made the Daimyo to change his mind.

Did Danzo use his sharingan's powers to become Hokage or was his speech good enough to convince the Daimyo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Danzō, rather than using the sharingan's ability, used the [Daimyō's](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Fire_Daimy%C5%8D) indecisive characteristic to his advantage - knowing he would side with whoever convinced him the most.

> The Fire Daimyō has a fickle and indecisive nature and is easily swayed in his decisions through biases as well as external influences. When situations call for fast, important decisions, he makes his advisers do the whole work: the one who convinces him most is the "winner"

Danzō convinced  the Daimyō that Kakashi, who was initially considered for becoming the 6th Hokage, maintained the same ideology that put Konoha in it's current state of crisis.

> However, Danzō points out that the teachings that were passed down to Kakashi were the cause of Konoha's problems and current crisis. The Konoha Crush, the frequent confrontations with Akatsuki, the defection of Sasuke Uchiha, and the destruction of Konoha's infrastructure, all stemmed from the ideology that kindness and unity would lead to peace. Danzō believed the ideology simply made Konoha appear weak and left them exposed to attacks

The Daimyō believed and agreed with Danzō

> The daimyō, persuaded by Danzō's words and reasoning, appointed Danzō as the Sixth Hokage Candidate, just in time for the Five Kage Summit.

Comment: Daimyos are stupid enough to be fooled just by words. No need to use any genjutsu technique to convince them.

Comment: @SahanDeSilva edited my answer to compliment your comment :)

Comment: haha.. I just wanted to point out that Daimyos are pretty useless (being normal humans with no shinobi skills) to guide and advice a set of people who have destructive power (E.g.: Any kage)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but spoiler alert

At first I thought he did use it but it does make sense that the daiymo changed his mind. It actually became more apparent later on when they were about to choose his replacement he leans over and says wheres the fellow with the one eye or something like that then says he scares me. I think that was actually put in to clear up any confusion about him using the eye. So it stands to reason that he just scared him into changing his mind when he got all stiff and rigid and stood up and raised his voice probably shook the daiymo. About his eye. I could be wrong but I remember reading or seeing something about that the eye takes a bit over a decade to be able to use again, however if suisui uses it because it was his eye I think it wont take anywhere near as long and as for donzo I think he actually said it after.he was caught using it but he said it will take 3 days or something like that for it to be able to be used again. The only reason why it is cut down tremendously for him and not for itachi Is because danzo has the hashirama cell implanted inside of him and it repairs its users body tremendously. Now I cant say I'm 100% about this info but I am pretty sure its accurate.

Answer (score -1):

It was activated until the fight with Sasuke, I don't remember why but it shuts for 10 years after being used for powerful genjutsu

Comment: When and where did this happen? danzo never used kotoamatsukami to become hokage.